# SSL installation on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I have updated my SSL certificate on CloudFront using Certificate Manager and invalidated all the distributions but I am still getting the old/expired certificate.

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that it's done in the us-east-1 region. If it's a new certificate rather than a renewal, you need to add the new one to the CloudFront Distribution.

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you also tried from a different computer?

Comment: When you say you "updated" the certificate... do you mean you [re-imported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-reimport.html) the certificate?

Comment: CloudFront normally needs about 30 minutes to apply it's changes to all edge locations.

Comment: @GeorgeRushby +1 to that

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I was importing the certificate to the same ARN which was working fine with all other services other than CloudFront. For CloudFront, I have to delete the older one and import as a new certificate to get the updated ARN which was then used in CloudFront for reference.

At the end, I was able to get it resolved myself.